# How do you know what licences you used in an Angular project?

Tags: npm

I'm working on a website that I plan to release as open source, and also publish it to a web host so that people can actually use it. The website uses Angular, and I used Angular CLI to create it. In order to install Angular CLI, I used npm.

I'm at the point in development where I want to host the website, but I want to make sure I comply with the licenses. It seems that when I use `ng build --prod` Angular CLI creates a `dist` folder where it puts the build files. It automatically creates a file called `3rdpartylicenses.txt`, which I assume is some attempt to collect the licenses for you.

However, it seems that the automatically generated `3rdpartylicenses.txt` is missing some libraries. For example, if I do `npm ls --prod`, the `3rdpartylicenses.txt` only contains about half of those. For example, I'm pretty sure that rxjs is a dependency of Angular, but it isn't listed anywhere in `3rdpartylicenses.txt`. Other libraries that I installed through npm are also missing (even though they show up in package.json).

I'm still new to npm and js, so maybe I am missing something, but does this mean that the only way to make sure you list all the licenses is to manually go through all the repositories and their dependencies and copy the licenses over each time? This seems like a very time consuming step and I'm guessing that other people must have run in to a similar workflow issue.

Comment: rxjs is a *peer* dependency of angular. I'm pretty sure `3rdpartylicenses.txt` only includes libraries you import ie get compiled to the output. For example, I have 2 apps in the same project app 1 imports lib A app 2 doesn't, only app 1's `3rdpartylicenses.txt` has lib A's license.

Answer (score 2):

Going through them manually is one way, but you could also try a tool such as [FOSSology](https://www.fossology.org/features) which scans all files in a software project to determine the licenses. It is both a command line program and accessible through a web interface that displays the results of a scan.

You mentioned that your automatically generated `3rdpartylicenses.txt` was missing some licenses. This tool is specifically designed for accuracy in detecting licenses:

> Nomos is one of FOSSology's license scanners. Nomos does license identification using short phrases (regular expressions) and heuristics, e.g. a phrase must be found in (or out of) proximity to another phrase or phrases. This helps to eliminate false positives.

I have not used this tool, but it seems to be what you are looking for. Judging by the screen shots and this [methodical review](http://studylib.net/doc/9551565/a-review-of-fossology---ryan-arnold) (starts on page 18), which found 100% accuracy in three test cases, it seems to be accurate indeed.

Comment: I am terribly biased.... but I would recommend to use instead https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit that I maintain... Among other things it is aware and detects node modules and my benchmarks show that it detects more license and more accurately than other scanners out there.